# LCOV doesn't show some classes

Tags: objective-c, tdd

I have an abstact UIViewController which has methods to test.

```
@interface ABViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *testResults;
- (void)test;
- (void)testFailedWithMessag:(NSString *)message;
@end

@implementation ABViewController
- (void)testFailedWithMessag:(NSString *)message
{
    if(self.testResults == nil)
    {
        self.testResults = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [self.testResults addObject:message];
}
@end
```

The basic idea of this class was to test private methods which are not listed on .h.

The test routines are implmented in the subclass's "test" method. as shown below.

RootViewController is a subclass of ABViewController.

```
@interface RootViewController ()
{
    UIButton *testButton;
}
@end

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    testButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
}

- (void)test
{
    if(testButton==nil)
        [self testFailedWithMessag:@"testButton is nil"];
}
@end
```

XCTest is as below.

```
- (void)testRootViewController
{
    // allocation class instance
    RootViewController *testClassInstance = [[RootViewController alloc] init];

    // when
    [testClassInstance view];

    // implement test
    [testClassInstance test];

    // verify result
    XCTAssertTrue(([[testClassInstance testResults] count] == 0), @"%@", [[testClassInstance testResults] description]);
}
```

I made several subclasses of ABViewController and ran the unit test. LCOV shows test coverage but it shows only ABViewController.

[image]

I want to see the all viewControllers in my project. Is there a way?
The number of functions are not matching with the functions of viewControllers. why?

Comment: I have the same problem !! you found any solution ?

Comment: Yes. The name on the list is DIRECTORY and it's also hoper-link.

Comment: Just click the directory name and you will see the classes in the directory